# Add new global react JSX attribute without @types scope in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Important: I don't want to specify anything into `tsconfig.json` please.

#### Error

```
Type '{ test: string; }' is not assignable to type
  'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.

Property 'test' does not exist on type
  'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.

ts(2322)
```

but `test` attribute is defined in `test_a` dependency (`test_a/index.d.ts`) as global extension to `react` dependency

---

## Root file

File `./package.json`

```json
{"dependencies":{"test_a":"1.0.0"}}
```

File `./index.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';

//                | Error
const test = <div test="hello" />;
```

---

### Dependency `test_a`

File `./node_modules/test_a/package.json`

```json
{"name":"test_a","types":"index.d.ts","version":"1.0.0"}
```

File `./node_modules/test_a/index.d.ts`

```js
import React from 'react';

declare global {
  namespace React {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
      test?: string;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use Typescript's [Declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). Create a file named *react.d.ts* or similar and put the following in it:

```
import 'react';

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    test?: string;
  }
}
```

This will extend the `HTMLAttributes` interface, adding the `test` field to it.